# extract multiple graphs stored in list made with purrr and plot in a single image

Tags: r, list, plot, purrr

Please, help me understand how to plot in one image all the histograms stored in a list made with purrr. 
This is a data example:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 X2 = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2),
                 X3 = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 3))
```

When I execute the next command, I get the plots, which I can browse in the viewer.

```
df %>% map(~hist(.))
```

I even got to the part of naming the elements of the list, which for my level of newbieness is amazing, by adding

```
%>% set_names( . , paste0("hist_" , names(df)))
```

I'd like to be able to plot in a single image all the histograms stored in the list obtained this way. If you could also explain how to pass the names of the elements to each histogram would be terrific.
PS: I know how to plot objects from the same family using facet_wrap and facet_grid. I don't think that applies to my question. Perhaps, gridExtra, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: `hist()` is a base graphics plot. It it not based on grid graphics or ggplot so function like `factet_grid` or any function from `gridExtra` aren't going to help. If you need to plot multiple base graphics plot, try looking at `layout()`. Also note that base graphics functions don't always return objects like `ggplot` does (though `hist` happens to be one of the few that does, though it does draw with side-effects immediately by default unless you set `plot=FALSE`).

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, I will look into `layout()`. Are you saying that I should be able to pipe the results from the list and get images? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm just warning you that that using old-school functions like `hist` with new-school functions like `map` and `%>%` probably isn't going to work the way you want. Just be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get multiple plots on one page with base graphics using the graphical parameter `mfrow`

```
 df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 X2 = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2),
                 X3 = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 3))
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
res <- df %>% map2(names(df) ,~hist(.x, main = .y)) #updated to make names work
```

But as MrFlick mentioned, you wold be better off using faceting like this

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% gather(var,value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_wrap(~var)
```

Comment: Hi @see24, incidentally, or better said, accidentally, while trying every crazy thought, i did stumble upon `par(mfrow = c())` but somehow, it didn't seem like a solution. But, anyway, it was the closest that i've gotten to, and now you're posting it so i guess it must be it. Do you have any ideas about how to pass the names to the plots?

Comment: See my edit. But again your life will be much easier it you just learn a little ggplot and use that package instead of the base version

Comment: Thank you, @see24! I've upvoted your answer, but because I'm new, it says it can't show my vote. But, thank you so much for taking the time to look into this. PS: I know how to make this plot with ggplot :) ggplot was the first thing I learned. I'm a far cry from being knowledgeable in it, but i can do most of the basic stuff with it without copy-pasting. But I really needed to learn how to do it this way too. So, thanks again.

Comment: If you are comitted to the base R hist-function, you can supply the names of your plots as the title argument of hist, which should be called either `main` or `title`.

Comment: Thanks @streamline55. Glad I could help. If the answer worked for you the best thing to do is to accept it by clicking the green arrow. That way other people know that you have the answer you need and they don't need to work on it (and I get reputation points).

Comment: @see24, Done! Sorry for the delay. Best of luck!